# Can't serialize class org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable - MongoDB Hadoop Connector + Spark + Python

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Following this good [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/using-mongodb-hadoop-spark-part-3-spark-example-key-takeaways) I found the [github repo](https://github.com/matthewkalan/mongodb-analytics-examples) of his code and I [cloned](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples) it to make it work easily for others.

I created a [script](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples/blob/master/setup.sh) to:

1. download and build [spark](https://github.com/apache/spark).
2. download, applies a patch and build [mongodb hadoop connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop).
3. download the [mongodb java driver v3.1.1 jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.1.1/mongodb-driver-3.1.1.jar).
4. put the minimum necessary jars together
5. download the [sample file](http://www.barchartmarketdata.com/data-samples/mstf.csv)
6. import it to a mongodb collection
7. install one necessary python library [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/)

It prepares everything to be ready to run.

The [python script](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples/blob/master/spark-ohlcbars-example.py) basically is this:

```py
config = {"mongo.input.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/marketdata.minbars"}
inputFormatClassName = "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat"
keyClassName = "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"
valueClassName = "org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable"

minBarRawRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(inputFormatClassName, keyClassName, valueClassName, None, None, config)
minBarRDD = minBarRawRDD.values()

import calendar, time, math
dateFormatString = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'     
groupedBars = minBarRDD.sortBy(lambda doc: str(doc["Timestamp"])).groupBy(lambda doc: 
    (doc["Symbol"], math.floor(calendar.timegm(time.strptime(doc["Timestamp"], dateFormatString)) / (5*60))))

def ohlc(grouping):
    # some

config["mongo.output.uri"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/marketdata.fiveminutebars"
outputFormatClassName = "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat"
# resultRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///placeholder", outputFormatClassName, None, None, None, None, config)
```

With that last line commented the when I run the [spark-ohlcbars-example.submit.sh](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples/blob/master/spark-ohlcbars-example.submit.sh) script everything goes perfectly without any error.

But once I uncomment the last line in onder to try to save the data back into mongodb the exception is raised

```
Can't serialize class org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable
```

I guess the process of converting from Python > Java > MongoDB format it gets lost when it tries to serialize and it doesn't work.

You can see the [issue](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples/issues/1) in the [git repository](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples)

I hope the community has a way for us to solve this problem. Do you guys know how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific problem was solved by using [pymongo_spark](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/affad1b7de2c167947c93930e9567447662de3b5/spark/src/main/python/pymongo_spark.py) on the commit hash **affad1b7**.

I copied the file to my project and added 3 lines of code on the main python script:

```py
import pymongo_spark
pymongo_spark.activate()
...
# at the end of the script
resultRDD.saveToMongoDB(config["mongo.output.uri"])
```

You can see the full diff on the github [commit](https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples/commit/f287620874038b2a491b50f48505c106299293fb)

https://github.com/danielsan/mongodb-analytics-examples/commit/f287620874038b2a491b50f48505c106299293fb